# SKPhysicsBody circleOfRadius area wrong

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8, skspritenode

Since Xcode 8.2.1 and iOS 10.2, I'm seeing (randomly) wrong area for SKPhysicsBody when constructed as circle. This is my code:

```
let boundingBox = (node.path)?.boundingBox
let radius = (boundingBox?.size.width)! / 2.0
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)

print("bubbleRadius: \(radius), boundingBox: \(boundingBox), physicsArea: \(node.physicsBody?.area), physicsAreaShouldBe: \((CGFloat.pi * radius/100 * radius/100))")
```

Now random factor. I couldn't find any clue when this printed 'physicsArea' is correct and when it's wrong. Sometimes print shows this (where you will see that area of PhysicsBody is calculated differently?):

> bubbleRadius: 50.0, boundingBox: Optional((-50.0, -50.0, 100.0,
>   100.0)), physicsArea: Optional(0.349065870046616), physicsAreaShouldBe: 0.785398163397448

And sometimes print shows this (where you can see that area is calculated normally - per my understanding of area of circle):

> bubbleRadius: 50.0, boundingBox: Optional((-50.0, -50.0, 100.0,
>   100.0)), physicsArea: Optional(0.785398185253143), physicsAreaShouldBe: 0.785398163397448

radius is always the same, only area gets calculated differently sometimes. This makes my circles overlap each other in the scene because  their body is smaler than it looks.

Any ideas what might this be? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you launch this code? in  `didMove(to view: SKView)` ?

Comment: This is happening in one of the 'SKShapeNode' subclasses. Node is being initialized, configured (where this part with 'SKPhysicsBody' happens) and then added to the 'SKScene' - way pass the 'didMove' moment.

Comment: 1 meter = 150 points, you may want to be dividing by 150, not 100 (Even though that does not solve your problem)

Comment: .34 would be the correct area.  A=pi * (50) * (50) = 7853.975 points squared.  then we divide by 150 squared (22500), to get 0.3490655555.

Comment: That is ok, but why is SDK calculating this 0.7... number at he 2nd load with the same radius? I'll make a video, to confirm a bug

Comment: The bug is on your end, you are not giving us all the code.  I wrote exactly what you have, and I am not getting any problem

Comment: Looks to me like your physics body radius is actually 75 some how, are you sure you are not doing any kind of scaling

Comment: I guess that the question is, does SKPhysicsBody uses anything else besides 'radius' to calculate the area? Radius, bounding box, that is always constant. I'll try to add more surrounding code and a video of what happens.